# Creating an 'if' statement based on the position of a value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to construct some `if` statements based on a particular position in a multi-value dictionary. My example dictionary and pseudocode are:

```
position1 = 0
position2 = 0
position1Unique = 0

exDict = {1: [800, 3, 0, 0], 2: [600, 0, 2, 1], 3: [900, 1, 5, 9]}

for value in exDict:
    if value_position1 > 0:
        position1 += 1
    if value_position2 > 0:
        position2 += 1
    if value_position1 > 0 AND value_position2 = 0 AND value_position3 = 0:
        position1Unique =+ 1
```

For this dictionary, my values would be:

```
position1 = 2
position2 = 2
position1Unique = 1
```

If it's not clear from the examples, the key/index and 0th-indexed value don't come into any calculations.

Comment: You'll need to rephrase this and rewrite some of the code to be clear about what the variable are meant to be, at the moment it's not clear what value_positionX or position1Unique signify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the values of a dictionary with `dict.values`. The values in `exDict` are ordinary lists, and you can index them with `[idx]` just like any other list.

```
position1 = 0
position2 = 0
position1Unique = 0

exDict = {1: [800, 3, 0, 0], 2: [600, 0, 2, 1], 3: [900, 1, 5, 9]}

for value in exDict.values():
    if value[1] > 0:
        position1 += 1
    if value[2] > 0:
        position2 += 1
    if value[1] > 0 and value[2] == 0 and value[3] == 0:
        position1Unique =+ 1

print(position1)
print(position2)
print(position1Unique)
```

Result:

```
2
2
1
```